# F# case insensitive string compare

Tags: f#

Is there a syntactically cleaner way to preform a case insensitive string comparison in F# than the following

```
System.String.Equals("test", "TeSt", System.StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about writing an extension method to make this shorter.

Comment: Wonderful suggestion, just to expand upon you answer I used the following

let (=?) s1 s2 = System.String.Equals(s1, s2, System.StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)

Answer (score 10):

Also, you can use [F# type extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233211%28VS.100%29.aspx) mechanics:

```
> type System.String with
-   member s1.icompare(s2: string) =
-     System.String.Equals(s1, s2, System.StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);;
> "test".icompare "tEst";;
val it : bool = true
```

Answer (score 0):

For any interested, a partial active pattern for this:

```
let (|InvariantEqualI|_|) (str:string) arg = 
  if String.Compare(str, arg, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) = 0
  then Some() else None
let (|OrdinalEqualI|_|) (str:string) arg = 
  if String.Compare(str, arg, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) = 0
  then Some() else None
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// Contains substring
(str1.ToUpper()).Contains (str2.ToUpper())
// Equality
(str1.ToUpper()).Contains (str2.ToUpper())
```

Comment: don't do that - you want to do an invariant comparison by passing the extra param to contains rather than allocating 2 clones every time. Also in some cases upper vs lower matters (turkish i etc), which is avoidable by doing the right thing in the first instance